# Scrollview doesn't scroll after resizing it's child using animation

Tags: android, scrollview, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. At some point I collapse and expand the LinearLayout. After that the scrollview does scroll. Any ideas?

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
........
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Expand and collapse is done using ValueAnimator over LayoutParams (height) of the LinearLayout.

**Update:** I think important is that it breaks down after animated expansion/collapse. Until that it works fine.

**Update 2:** For expanding again, I measured the expected height as follows:

```
  int expectedHeight = detailsView.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

and animate expansion to that height. This measured the height to 2000+ instead of expected 800 something. Thus the sizes were equal and scrollview didn't scroll, although it didn't show the full hierarchy.

As a quick-fix I save the current height before collapsing and use it as the target height on expanding. The question is, can this be done automatically without dirty-height saving?

Comment: I think screenshot is useless - just two views, one inside the other, can't show dynamics by the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

your scrollview is `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` just make it `match_parent`. I'm not sure but you can remove `android:fillViewport` too

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
........
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the scrollview only scroll if content size is > as the scrollview size, can you send a screenshot of before & after please ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think I understood what was the issue - was debugging and same thing crossed my mind: before the collapse, LinearLayout's height is 818, after the expansion it is 2257. So, when I expand LinearLayout, ScrollView gets expanded, too, thus not scrolling anything. Will check for ScrollView size now.